# Spring's @Autowired not injecting a Map - am I even using it correctly?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm trying to add some Spring configuration to an existing utility class. It doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why (my first time using these Spring options, I'm not even sure I'm doing it correctly).

The class in question

```
@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME, preConstruction=true)
public class DataUtility
{
    private static final DataUtility INSTANCE = new DataUtility();

    @Autowired(required=true) //This is the new field and annotation
    private Map<String,String> dataFileMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static DataUtility getInstance()
    {
         return INSTANCE;
    }

    private DataUtility()
    {
         //Do a bunch of setup work here
         for (String s : dataFileMapping)
         {
              addDataToCache(dataFileMapping(s))
         }
    }
```

The spring config looks like this:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<bean id="util" class="com.myCompany.DataUtility">
    <property name="dataFileMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="data1" value="data/file1.dat"/>
            <entry key="data2" value="data/file2.dat"/>
            <entry key="data3" value="data/file3.dat"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that when I step through my code in the debugger, I can see that `dataFileMapping` is empty. I'm not even sure if the spring config is even running.

Comment: This bean configuration just can't work(because there is no public constructor), is it a web application?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov: It is a web application.

Comment: How are the dispatcher servlet/web app root spring contexts configured(in web.xml)? have you specified name of the configuration xml file?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov: The configuration file that configures this bean configures several others, and they all work fine.

Comment: If there is no public constructor, it's very unlikely that Spring will be able to instantiate DataUtility with the configuration specified, I think there must be something like `factory-method="getInstance"` inside the `util` bean declaration.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov: I had thought that `@Configurable` was needed for this sort of thing, but I may have misunderstood it. As for why I'm doing this in the first place... I was told to make it more configurable, so that the data names and paths could be loaded by Spring. I would have just used simple property files if I could, but Spring was what I was told.

Comment: Sorry it's not my day, I confused `@Configurable` with `@Configuration` ) But still why can't this object live inside the container(instead of being a Java singleton)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20352/discussion-between-boris-treukhov-and-frustratedwithformsdesigner)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add getters and setters for dataFileMapping

Also, remember that you can't iterate through the map in the constructor, spring wouldn't have had a chance to set it until after the constructor executes.

In addition to this, you can't make your constructor private and expect spring to be able to instantiate it.

Comment: From what I've read, `@Autowired` should work even on private members, so getters/setters shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is that you seem to be using a static reference INSTANCE to access the object.  Spring is making a bean named 'util' and setting it up with your data, but that isn't becoming the object that INSTANCE points to.  The initialization of static fields happens when the class is first loaded, long before spring ever gets a chance to create and inject beans.

You can sort of fake it like this, but of course attempts to access instance before bean initialization will fail:

```
@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME, preConstruction=true)
public class DataUtility
{
    private static final DataUtility INSTANCE = null;

    @Autowired(required=true) //This is the new field and annotation
    private Map<String,String> dataFileMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static DataUtility getInstance()
    {
         return INSTANCE;
    }

    public postInit()
    {
         INSTANCE = this;
         //Do a bunch of setup work here
         for (String s : dataFileMapping)
         {
              addDataToCache(dataFileMapping(s))
         }
    }


    <bean id="util" class="com.myCompany.DataUtility" init-method="postInit">
        <property name="dataFileMapping">
            <map>
                <entry key="data1" value="data/file1.dat"/>
                <entry key="data2" value="data/file2.dat"/>
                <entry key="data3" value="data/file3.dat"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I think `INSTANCE` would also have to be non-final.